# Whenever I run apt I get a string of errors about a failed attempt to remove an old kernel. What should I do?

Tags: apt, package-management

```
afaan@afaan-VivoBook-ASUS-Laptop-X505ZA-X505ZA:~$ sudo apt purge libplymouth2
[sudo] password for afaan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libplymouth2* linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 1672 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 194 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 221803 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic (3.13.0-32.57) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: a#: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic (3.13.0-32.57) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: a#: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: `/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: a#: not found`

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: `1672 not upgraded` - your system is seriously deficient with maintenance.  1672 packages not upgraded means that your software is extremely out of date and that you have not performed updates in a very long time.  Please run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade` before you attempt to install any new software.  If you continue to have issues, please post the results of those commands as an edit.

Answer (score 3):

Make a backup from your personal datas. you have a somekind of typo in /etc/default/grub and not since today I think.

```
sudo mv /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.broken
```

Now we restore the file to default.

```
sudo cp -a /usr/share/grub/default/grub /etc/default/grub
```

this kernel versions are very old. I would make a clean install of an supported release like ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @someone I'm not an expert. the problem lies in a corruppted /etc/default/grub. so the incomming kernel never get correct installt. because after installing a new kernel update-grub will be called and this failes.